# LogRhythm SOAP Api problems

Tags: soap

Anyone here manage to get something from LR soap API ?

My query is quite simple, here is an extract:

```
<soap:Body>
    <GetAlarmHistoryByID
        xmlns="http://www.logrhythm.com/webservices"
        xmlns:ns2="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays"
        xmlns:ns3="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">
        <alarmID>140</alarmID>
        <includeNotifications>false</includeNotifications>
        <includeComments>false</includeComments>
    </GetAlarmHistoryByID>
</soap:Body>
```

I receive the following in response, which makes no sense, because of "Include notifcations or include comments is required." but the values are found lower: 
includeNotifications: 140 include comments: False (inversed from the values i passed...)

```
  <s:Fault>
        <faultcode>s:Client</faultcode>
        <faultstring xml:lang="en-US">Include notifcations or include comments is required.</faultstring>
        <detail>
            <LogRhythmWebServiceFault
                xmlns="http://www.logrhythm.com/webservices"
                xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
                <FaultID>4d12a9ed-bff7-4dfb-ad71-29372c12544d</FaultID>
                <Details>Error getting Alarm history (includeNotifications: 140 include comments: False) for ID False</Details>
                <FaultTime>2017-09-07T17:46:22.5779477Z</FaultTime>
                <ErrorID>3024</ErrorID>
            </LogRhythmWebServiceFault>
        </detail>
    </s:Fault>
```

Method: GetAlarmHistoryByID

Retrieve a list of alarm status and comment updates. The Alarm ID would be derived from one of the `GetFirstPageAlarms` or a `GetNextPageAlarms` method call.

```
alarmID long No The unique ID of the alarm.
includeNotifications boolean No If true, include notification history.
includeComments boolean No If true, include comments history.
```

Output
The alarm history.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and it ended up being a bug with the calls on LogRhythm's side. I'd advise to make a ticket with them for a resolution.  If you haven't figured it out yet